# CSS: how to calculate margin inside a div for a fluid layout

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a fluid responsive layout.
In the aside I have 8 blocks as shown below:

```
<aside id="sub-content">

<div class="sub-box">
<article class="sub-art">
<h2>Mid Sidebar</h2>
<p>
text...
</p>
</article>
</div>
</aside>
```

...and so on

The class "sub-art" has been formatted as following:

```
#sub-content  .sub-art{
background:#ffffff;
margin: 0px;
padding: 10px 15px;
margin-left: 10px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
overflow:hidden;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
border-top-left-radius: 8px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;    
}
```

As you can see in the [example](http://jsfiddle.net/web_garaux/80z6vp46/3/) the first article class="sub-art" should be align to the div called **Second post**.

How can I correct the margin-right in order to obtain 8 blocks well alligned?

Comment: You'll need to be clearer about what you are trying to achieve. Quite confusing. Which 8 blocks? I saw 12, and you don't have any div with id="sub-art" in the jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way to do it:

```
#sub-content {
  width: auto;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: -10px;
  margin-right: -10px;
}

#sub-content .sub-box {
  width: 25%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

#sub-content .sub-art {
  background: #ffffff;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top-left-radius: 8px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
}
```

I'm applying a negative margin to the `#sub-content` element and using padding rather than margins to create the gutters in the `.sub-box` elements. I also removed the margins from the `.sub-art` elements. Also, notice that I set box sizing on the `.sub-box` elements to `border-box`. This is necessary to prevent the padding from increasing the size of the box.

http://jsfiddle.net/80z6vp46/6/

This method is basically the same thing Bootstrap 3 does.

Answer (score 0):

May be not the smartest solution, but just add

```
#sub-content .left-most-element {
    margin-left: 0px;
}
```

to your .css file and the new class to your "left most elements" (1 and 5)

```
<article class="sub-art left-most-element">
```

This should do the trick ;)